# How can I grow ginger in my backyard?

Tags: raised-beds, root-vegetables, ginger

I have never grown ginger and want to try to in my raised beds in my backyard.  I don't have ginger seeds to grow from but can I cut sections of ginger I buy from the store and grow it?  Any other guidelines to how to start growing ginger would be appreciated such as seasons to start "seeding" and harvesting would be appreciated. I am in USDA Hardiness Zone 9b

Comment: I have a few types of ginger in my yard, the rhizomes/roots  root readily making it almost invasive ( in the right climate).

Answer (score 7):

You should really wait till late winter (in pots if its not warm enough outdoors) or spring time to plant, but assuming it's ginger root you're after, then yes, you can buy it from the grocery store - select pieces which look plump, with as many 'eyes' as you can find. Soak them overnight, then either cut them up, making sure there's an eye in each piece (that's where growth comes from), or plant whole. They like free draining yet moisture retaining, fairly rich soil, and a sheltered spot with dappled sunlight - they wilt in direct sun. They don't like frost, and the warmer your climate, the better your harvest. Improve the soil you're planting into by adding composted materials beforehand. More info here http://www.tropicalpermaculture.com/growing-ginger.html